# How can I make R print printed column names vertically?

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose, output-formatting, r-colnames

I believe in meaningful variable names. Unfortunately this often means that there are huge white gaps when I look at a data.frame in the R console:

[image]

Is there a way to tell R to print the column names vertically, like this:

[image]

It doesn't need to be in the console, maybe it is possible to plot a table to PDF that way?

---

Executable code, provided by Ben Bolker:

```
sample.table <- data.frame(a.first.long.variable.name=rep(1,7),
                           another.long.variable.name=rep(1,7),
                           this.variable.name.is.even.longer.maybe=rep(1,7)
                           )
```

Comment: Please provide your code as text so readers can copy and paste it into their R console.

Comment: I guess you could render it as an HTML table and apply rotation via CSS. E.g. `library(DT); datatable(setNames(mtcars, sprintf('<div style="transform:rotate(-90deg);">%s</div>', names(mtcars))), escape = F) ` (Maybe you can apply `formatStyle` to column headers, but I didn't see how)

Comment: That's an idea, thanks @lukeA.

Comment: @lukeA do you mind making your comment as answer, can't get it to work...

Comment: @zx8754 Did you try it in the Browser or just in the RStudio Viewer? Still seems to work for me in a browser.

Comment: @lukeA Yes, right, it works in a browser but not in a viewer. Please post as an answer.

Comment: @zx8754 yep, done.

Answer (score 5):

As described in the comments, you may apply rotation via CSS:

```
library(DT)
df <- mtcars
names(df) <- sprintf('<div style="transform:rotate(-90deg);margin-top:30px;">%s</div>', names(df))
dt <- datatable(df, escape = FALSE)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(dt, tf<-tempfile(fileext = ".html"))
shell.exec(tf)
```

This does not work in the RStudio Viewer, however it does work in the browser:

[image]

Comment: Any way to adjust the height of column names? For example, try above code with `colnames(df)[1] <- "looooong_naaaame"`

Comment: @zx8754 Add something in the veins of `line-height:100px` to the css?

Comment: Did you find out how to change the line height? Would like to use it too

Answer (score 1):

Not without using a graphics device.
A better and simpler workaround which works in a plain old console is:
Print the **transpose** of the table, now column-names become row-names:

```
> t(sample.table)
                                        1 2 3 4 5 6 7
a.first.long.variable.name              1 1 1 1 1 1 1
another.long.variable.name              1 1 1 1 1 1 1
this.variable.name.is.even.longer.maybe 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

(To suppress the useless column-names you get by default, include `sample.table <- data.frame(row.names=1:7, ...` )

I do this all the time. Heatmaps, dendrograms, auto-named regression variables from expanding categoricals...